# Found this line in my .htaccess, what does it mean?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

My hosting provider switched to a new VPS yesterday so I've spent the day making sure all my files are sorted out as they should be.

I've gone to access one of my subdomains today and instead of display the HTML/PHP pages, they've been downloading themselves to my computer. I decided to check the .htaccess file that had been stored on the server, and the one that is on my local machine (that I have written), and they don't match -- this had this line in:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php
```

I commented the line out (by putting a # in front of it) and tried to access my HTML/PHP pages again and they loaded as expected.

What does this line of .htaccess mean, why is it there and why does it do what it does?

I never put the line there, it seems to have only happened after moving VPS.

Files such as images were displaying as expected.

Comment: It is used to switch to PHP 7

Comment: @JayBlanchard oh right, thanks. Do you happen to know why it is downloading my files rather than displaying them?

Answer (score 0):

That is to switch your site to PHP7. Normally, to make things backwards compatible, it would be something like this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Comment: Oh right, thanks. Do you happen to know why it is downloading my files rather than displaying them?

Comment: It's likely because they only added the type and did not add the handler.

Comment: so do I need to put both lines (the one that was auto-added, and the one you provided in your answer) into my .htaccess?

Comment: You can do that, but I would hit up the host and let them know they've not configured your VPS correctly. If they made this change they may have made others which are having an effect. There is no harm in changing the htaccess file.

Comment: I would also recommend that you check your site is compatible with PHP 7, I've had  this issue before and seen others that have too, when files were downloading rather than being processed when updating to PHP 7. Try rolling back to PHP 5.5, and if your files are now being processed, you know there is an incompatibility.